# ::selection pseudo selector ignoring ::before pseudo element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, cross-browser, pseudo-element

I am using Clipboard.js to copy a `.container`'s contents to the user's clipboard. I have styled the `::selection` / `::-moz-selection` of this `.container` and it's child elements as all child elements are `.select()`ed during the copy to clipboard process.

It works great except for on `::before` (and presumably `::after`) pseudo elements. `::before` more or less ignores my css declarations. I am using the `counter` css property in `::before` as `content`.

Here is a snippet exposing the issue. I have not included any JS as it is not necessary to expose the issue. Click and drag on the code block and you will see that no content is highlighted on `::selection` except for the `::before` pseudo element.

Can anyone show me how to override `::selection` of `::before` pseudo element so that it is not visible?

**Edit: This seems to be a Safari/Chrome (presumably `-webkit-` issue). Not happening in Firefox after doing a bit of isolation testing.**

[image: ::before still being selected]

```css
.html.container {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 padding: .9375rem .9375rem .9375rem 2.5rem;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background: rgba(38, 38, 38, .08);
 counter-reset: lines;
}
.html.container::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
    left: 0;
 width: 5px;
 height: 100%;
 background: grey;
}

.html.syntax {
 display: block;
 border-left: .0625rem solid black;
}

.html.syntax *::selection {
 background: transparent;
 color: inherit;
}

.html.syntax *::-moz-selection {
 background: transparent;
 color: inherit;
}

.html.line::before {
 content: counter(lines);
 position: absolute;
 left: 5px;
 width: 25px;
    color: grey;
 text-align: right;
 transition: all .25s ease;
}
.html.line {
 display: block;
 padding-left: 15;
 counter-increment: lines;
}

.html.line::before::selection {
 background: transparent;
 color: inherit;
}

.html.syntax::before::-moz-selection {
 background: transparent;
 color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="js html container" data-clipboard-target="#\<h1\>">
 <code class="html syntax" id="<h1>">
  <span class="html line">
   <span class="html comment">&lt;!-- Heading level 1 --&gt;</span>
  </span>
  <span class="html line">
   &lt;<span class="html tag">h1</span>&gt;Heading level 1&lt;<span class="html tag">/h1</span>&gt;
  </span>
 </code>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a data attribute on the "html line" classed span, this prevents the number from appearing in the selection in Chrome. The downside to this is you'll lose the CSS counter to auto-increment the line numbers:

```
<div class="js html container" data-clipboard-target="#\<h1\>">
    <code class="html syntax" id="<h1>">
        <span class="html line" data-pseudo-content="1">
            <span class="html comment">&lt;!-- Heading level 1 --&gt;</span>
        </span>
        <span class="html line" data-pseudo-content="2">
            &lt;<span class="html tag">h1</span>&gt;Heading level 1&lt;<span class="html tag">/h1</span>&gt;
        </span>
    </code>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ohyj81c4/

[image: Lines with data-attributes selected on Chrome]

ref https://danoc.me/blog/css-prevent-copy/

The reason you can't change the pseudo element selection colour is because you can only use 1 pseudo-element in a selector. Both ::selection and ::before come under this definition, rather than ::selection being a [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pseudo-classes) like :active, :visited etc.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Comment: Thanks for this @jonnow. Functionally this works exactly as I want it, and the `::before` content is not copied to the clipboard. Which is great. But for UX/Design/ Aesthetic purposes I wanted to remove the highlighting of the `::before` pseudo-elements. Thanks for reminding me you can only use one pseudo-element in a selector. I would have thought that they wouldn't ignore one another though.

Comment: Thanks for this. This does look like a workable solution. What is the reasoning for `data-pseudo-content="4"` being applied to `span.html.tag` in your example? I don't follow that part of the solution.

Comment: A mistype on my part :D

Comment: This is obviously going to make things more manual. But it solves my problems. Thanks. Now to read up on custom data attributes...